On reindexing, catalogsearch_fulltext, stack on status processing
I am working on a magento 2.4.2 store with about 5000 products on a Plesk (Obsidian 18.0.52 + AlmaLinux 8.8) dedicate server.
The customer complain' s than new products not appear on frontend.
On SSH terminal with "php bin/magento indexer:status" command i get the result:



ID
Title
Status
Update On
Schedule Status




catalogrule_product
Catalog Product Rule
Ready
Save



catalogrule_rule
Catalog Rule Product
Ready
Save



catalogsearch_fulltext
Catalog Search
Processing
Save



catalog_category_product
Category Products
Ready
Save



customer_grid
Customer Grid
Ready
Save



design_config_grid
Design Config Grid
Ready
Save



inventory
Inventory
Ready
Save



catalog_product_category
Product Categories
Ready
Save



catalog_product_attribute
Product EAV
Ready
Save



catalog_product_price
Product Price
Ready
Save



cataloginventory_stock
Stock
Ready
Save




As you can see process "catalogsearch_fulltext" appears with status "Processing".
I reset "catalogsearch_fulltext" with "php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogsearch_fulltext" command and then again reindexing with "php bin/magento indexer:reindex".
Now the new products appear' s on frontend.
I have create a cron job which every half hour reindexing products, but after 2-3 execution's, status on catalogsearch_fulltext return to "Processing". It is need to reset catalogsearch_fulltext and then reindexing again.
I can' t do this every day. Any idea?

I need help for this issues plz.
I increased the memory usage for mysql by editing the my.cnf file. From 765MB to 4G. But there was no improvement.

Try changing the Update On to schedule. If you have anything (such as a stock feed) that is updating the products it would cause the catalogsearch_fulltext to run. We had this issue with one of our sites and this resolved the issue. Just make sure you have your cron running, otherwise it will never be triggered.

Thnk @Daniel Black. I turn all processes on "update by schedule", cronjob run, but still the same problem, catalogsearch_fulltext stay with status "Processing"

We had this same problem and we found that the process that made the index was consuming too much memory and was killed by the OOM on the kernel, which leaved this on inconsistent status. We saw that using the dmesg command
Please, check your server maximum caps, and check the var/log/error.log file to see if you see something related to that.

Oh yes i have many fatals errors because of memory:
2024-09-19 11:01:19.530643 [NOTICE] [1777243] [T0] [35.205.159.124:32772#APVH_glowfashion.gr:443] [STDERR] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1399975936) (tried to allocate 67108872 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/glowfashion.gr/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291\n
and others like this on files:
/ErrorHandler.php, /SaveHandler.php, /Pdo.php
So I need to further increase the memory usage from the file my.cnf?
The server has 64GB memory. how much do i need to add?

Not the my.cnf file, the php.ini file. You are getting error on PHP, not MySQL. You should be able to modify the  values formemory_limit = 1024M or HIgher. See this official guide

Also, check to apply the following patches:
MDVA-38608: Temporary tables not deleted for unsuccessful reindexes
MDVA-40550: Products missing on the frontend after reindexing

Thnx Serfe. Yes i increased memory_limit = 20000M via php.ini and reindexing works with no errors. I will also check the links you sent because I seem to be experiencing the same issues. Thanx again.

Hi Serfe, those patches are for Adobe Commerce version only? Because we use magento opensource version.

Yes, should work for your setup. be aware that Magento => Adobe Commerce. See this guide to know how to apply patches.

Try check for database locks that might be causing the indexer to get stuck
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

The magento creates a lock file to avoid running the same indexer, check if have any file .lock
find var/locks/ -type f -name '*.lock'

If u find lock file related to catalogsearch_fulltext, u can delete the file
rm var/locks/indexer_catalogsearch_fulltext.lock

